# angularjs set height of div based on width

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am trying to set the height of a div based on its width, and then applying a multiplication factor. I am using angularjs in my code, and I need to use the class to base the directive on.

my html is as follows:

```
<div ng-class="(box.banner) ? 'bannerbox col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-4' : 'cardbox col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-4'"  ng-repeat="box in boxes">
```

If the div is a bannerbox (ie has the bannerbox class) then I need the height of this div to be 1.08571 * the width. I understand I need to do this using a directive, but not sure where I am going wrong. My directive code is as follows:

```
app.directive('bannerbox', function () {
return {
    restrict: "C",
    link: function (scope, element) {
        element.height(element.width * 1.08571);
    }
}
```

});

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What is your error/problem? What happens with your directive?

Comment: sorry I forgot to add. The height is not altered from its natural state, so I do not thing the directive is working. I wondered if this was because this code is dynamically loaded using ng-view.

Comment: also, the class is set correctly using ng-class so this is not the problem.

Comment: Did you try my solution ? Is it working for you ?

Comment: Hi Timothee - I can see it working in the fiddle, but I cannot get it to work with my code. I cannot understand why but I do not think the directive is triggered although it is definately loaded.

Comment: It does work when I use restrict: "A" and add an element of bannerbox="" but it doesnt work with the class. Could this be to do with ng-class? is it possible to add an element dynamically instead...

Comment: I fixed it using attributes with a value. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, sorry I didn't respond earlier. Great to see that it's working for you. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to watch for the width of the element because the width's value is zero initially.

When the link function is called, the width of the element is zero.

Assuming you're using `angularJs` and `jQuery`:

```
app.directive('bannerbox', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, element) {
            scope.getWidth = function () {
                return $(element).width();
            };
            scope.$watch(scope.getWidth, function (width) {
                // Do your work with the element width.
                // Be careful not to change the width of the element or you will create an infinite loop.
                // Set the height of the element.
            });
        }
   }
});
```

Working JsFiddle example here : http://jsfiddle.net/ZtQ2p/